# How to check projects preview on site.com

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

Hello I am facing problem finding page preview in site.com.
Site.com providing a platform to build websites and sales force and cloud related operations..

My client gave me requirements about project..project is already there we have to modified project sites content.
I am unable to find pages.

test User (My account) -- In this image you can see the site.com option

[image]

Client Account -- But here site.com option is not present
[image]

I am new for sales force and site.com I did R&D and all but not able to figure out.
Please help me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Site.com is by default available in Developer Edition and is available on purchase for Enterprise and Unlimited edition.

You can compare the feature differences by navigating to Setup--> Administration Setup --> Company Profile --> Company Information.

You will be able to see Site.com Publisher User and Site.com Contributor User features licenses available by default in your developer account and these licenses won't be there by default in the client account. For enabling Site.com Publisher User and Site.com Contributor User licenses in your client account, you will need to raise a hep desk ticket to Salesforce and make necessary payments for the licenses.

This link will help you to dig more into enabling these Site.com licenses.
http://ap1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/siteforce_admin_setup.htm

If you already have these licenses setup in the client account, please check if the user with which you are logging into client account has the checkboxes named Site.com Publisher User and/or Site.com Contributor User marked as checked. You can find the user settings by navigating to Setup --> Administration Setup --> Manage Users --> Users --> and open the concerned user. If unchecked, mark it checked.

Hope this helps.